# PostGIS: How to create a table with a generic 3D GEOMETRY column?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, fme

While attempting to import geometry information from a CAD drawing into PostGIS, I am having a problem with 3D geometries being coerced into 2D. The dataset that is being worked contains both 2D and 3D objects. Unfortunately, the tool I am using for the import respects the value of `coord_dimensions` in the `geometry_columns` view which is being set to 2 upon table creation.

**Goal:** Have a geometry column that treats all objects as 3D and defaults Z values to 0 when not found.

---

Here is my current table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cad_geom
( id                      BIGSERIAL    PRIMARY KEY
, created                 TIMESTAMPTZ  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, updated                 TIMESTAMPTZ  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, _refid                  BIGINT       DEFAULT NULL
, autocad_block_name      TEXT 
, autocad_block_number    INTEGER
, autocad_entity_handle   TEXT
, autocad_entity          TEXT
, autocad_source_filename TEXT
, geom                    GEOMETRY     NOT NULL
);
```

1. How can I use the generic `GEOMETRY` type and have a table that expects 3D coordinates from creation time?
2. Are there any suggestions for updating the value of `coord_dimensions` in the `geometry_columns` view? What tables and columns need adjusting?

**Note:** My dataset includes many different `GEOMETRY` types such as, `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z`, `POLYGON`, etc. so I believe the generic type is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AddGeometryColumn.

```
 AddGeometryColumn(varchar schema_name, varchar table_name, varchar column_name, integer srid, varchar type, integer dimension, boolean use_typmod=true);
```

Adds a geometry column to an existing table of attributes.

The **srid** must be an integer value reference to an entry in the SPATIAL_REF_SYS table. 
The **type** must be a string corresponding to the geometry type, eg, 'POLYGON' or 'MULTILINESTRING' .

Check this [working example](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html),  it solves all your questions.

Comment: Since that is requiring a geometry type such as polygon or multilinestring, does that limit the column to allow only those types? I viewed the post you linked here earlier and that was my concern with the answer there.

Comment: No,  it states clearly "eg",  example.  It also states that the AddGeometryColumn is conformant to OpenGis specification,  so it allows all datatypes allowd for GIS data,  for example it allows curvepolygon.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was under the impression that the `AddGeometryColumn(...)` function was not applicable to my use case due to the examples provided in the documentation having specific geometry types such as, `POLYGON` or `MULTILINESTRING` as well as, my data not containing an `SRID`. This data provided came from a mechanical CAD drawing where there is no projection onto the globe.

Turns out you can indeed use `AddGeometryColumn(...)` like the following example:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('cad', 'cad_geom', 'geom', 0, 'GEOMETRY', 3);
```